# Segfault when trying to printf pointer-to-object stored in member std::array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this program where I have a `Person` object that has a `std::array<Person*, x>` in it.

I add pointers in each `Person` to other `Person`s who are their friends.

Now inside an instance of `Person`, I can examine the pointers-to-`Person`s in its own array and see the names of the friends. But if I examine the whole array, from my `main()` function for instance, and try to access the friends from there, I get a segfault.

Here is my Person.h

```
#ifndef TOO2_PERSON_H
#define TOO2_PERSON_H

#include <string>
#include <array>

class Person {
    std::string name;
    int id_code;
    std::array<Person*, 10> friends;
    int friends_count;
public:
    const std::string &getName();
    void setName(const std::string& name);

    int getId_code();
    void setId_code(int id_code);

    std::array<Person*, 10>* getFriends();
    void addFriend(Person* person);

    Person();
    Person(const Person &obj);
    ~Person();
};


#endif //TOO2_PERSON_H
```

And here are the relevant methods in Person.cpp:

```
    #include "Person.h"

const std::string& Person::getName() {
    return Person::name;
}

void Person::setName(const std::string& name) {
    Person::name = name;
}

int Person::getId_code() {
    return Person::id_code;
}

void Person::setId_code(int id_code) {
    Person::id_code = id_code;
}

void Person::addFriend(Person* person) {
    Person::friends[friends_count] = person;
    printf("\nNAme: %s", friends[friends_count]->getName().c_str());
    Person::friends_count++;
}

std::array<Person*, 10>* Person::getFriends() {
    return &friends;
}

Person::Person(const Person &obj) {
    Person::name = obj.name;
    Person::id_code = obj.id_code;
    Person::friends = obj.friends;
}

Person::~Person() {
    //printf("%s deleted", Person::name.c_str());
}

Person::Person() {
    Person::friends_count = 0;
}
```

Here is the code in `main()` that throws an error:

```
Persons p = Persons();
Person taavi;
taavi.setName("Taavi");
taavi.setId_code(121421);
p.addPerson(taavi);

Person teele;
teele.setName("Teele");
teele.setId_code(22131);
p.addPerson(teele);

taavi.addFriend(&teele);
teele.addFriend(&taavi);

printf("\n%s", p.getPersons()[0].getFriends()->at(0)->getName().c_str());
```

Persons.h and Persons.cpp

```
#ifndef TOO2_PERSONS_H
#define TOO2_PERSONS_H

#include <array>
#include "Person.h"

class Persons {
    int persons_count;
    std::array<Person, 10> persons;
public:
    int getPersons_count();
    void setPersons_count(int persons_count);
    std::array<Person, 10> getPersons();
    void addPerson(Person person);
    const Person findPersonByName(std::string& name);
    Persons();
};

#endif //TOO2_PERSON_H

#include "Persons.h"

std::array<Person, 10> Persons::getPersons() {
    return Persons::persons;
}

void Persons::setPersons_count(int persons_count) {
    Persons::persons_count = persons_count;
}

int Persons::getPersons_count() {
    return Persons::persons_count;
}


void Persons::addPerson(Person person) {
    Persons::persons[persons_count] = person;
    Persons::persons_count++;
}

Persons::Persons() {
    Persons::persons_count = 0;
}

const Person Persons::findPersonByName(std::string &name) {
    Person person = Person();
    for(int i = 0; i < Persons::persons_count; i++) {
        if(Persons::persons[i].getName() == name) {
            person = Persons::persons[i];
        }
    }

    return person;
}
```

So the last `printf` is throwing an error. The program finishes with code `139`.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: The printf is throwing error when I ask the name of the friend from the array. I can fetch the array it self fine.

Comment: I think that giving a look at `Persons` constructor could be useful

Comment: So which part of that printf throws the error? produce a minimal example.

Comment: Why do you use a fixed-size type for something like `friends`? It should probably be an `std::set`. Also `Person::` qualification isn't necessary here and is making the code harder to read. And it's not clear which part of the instruction is producing an error. Split it up into subexpressions or run under the debugger and inspect the call stack. And don't return the pointer to the `std::array` of pointers, a reference should be used instead, and even then you shouldn't return a concrete data structure here where a range would suffice.

Comment: Added the whole Person.cpp so that the constructors could be seen also. The printf() throws error when I try to access the getName() function. I can get the array from the class but the array that I get back does not have the correct pointers to the Person's that I added to it I guess.

Comment: Those are pointers, not references.

Comment: We would need to see the definition and implementation of your `Persons` collection too.

Comment: Added them to the answer also.

Comment: Does `printf` provide any error text? Also, further emphasis that you should use a `std::set` rather than a static `array`; then not only would everything be safer, but you wouldn't be reinventing the wheel by manually maintaining things like `persons_count`. (Most people would suggest a `std::vector` by default, but assuming you never want duplicate `Person`s or friends, a `set` has this check built-in for you by hashing on the pointer.)

Comment: @underscore_d, `std::set` doesn't hash anything.

Comment: All I get when I run the program is this: Process finished with exit code 139. And I will try to use std::set also then. But the thing I am trying to is pretty simple so I thought that I could use this simpler array for such a little task.

Comment: My feeling is that because getPersons returns the vector persons by value -- this is usually source of headache. you should return a const& instead.

Comment: @A.S.H You mean something like this: const std::array<Person*, 10>& getFriends();   ?

Comment: yes this is what I meant. In fact your code is using default copy constructors of Person, implicitly, and it is not guaranteed to work well. Change params as well as return values into const& wherever you can.

Comment: @JonathanWakely My bad, getting concepts mixed up. `std::set` uses `<` operators to ensure uniqueness, and these work on pointers out-of-the-box. @A.S.H: Great points; by-value should be avoided unless we know for sure it's needed.

Comment: @Kaspar, "this simpler array" is a simpler data structure, but it's not simpler to use. It is much easier to use it wrong, as you are doing. You create the array so it contains pointers with unsafe garbage values, then you don't ensure you are accessing a valid array element when you do `getFriends()->at(0)` so you dereference a garbage pointer. A better design using smarter data structures would prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds **a copy** of `taavi` to the `Persons` collection:

```
p.addPerson(taavi);
```

Then this creates a relationship between `teele` and the *original* `taavi` object, not the copy you added to `p`:

```
taavi.addFriend(&teele);
```

Also, your `getPersons()` function returns a copy of the array, so it makes *copies of the copies* in the `Persons` collection!

So this accesses a copy of the copy of `taavi`:

```
printf("\n%s", p.getPersons()[0].getFriends()->at(0)->getName().c_str());
```

The copy has no friends, so `getFriends()->at(0)` returns an uninitialized pointer, because you didn't zero the array in the `Person` constructor:

```
Persons::Persons() {
    Persons::persons_count = 0;
}
```

The code is a really fragile design, stop using a fixed-size array that contains uninitialized pointers. Stop adding copies to the `Persons` collection. Either define a correct copy constructor or prevent copies from being made.

The API of your class is extremely error-prone. The `std::array` should be an implementation detail, not part of the API. That would allow you to replace it with a different data structure without rewriting all the code that uses the `Person` class. Instead of `getFriends()` returning the raw array you could have a `getFriend(int)` function, which can do some error-checking:

```
Person* Person::getFriend(int n) {
    if (n < friend_count)
        return friends[n];
    else
        throw std::range_error("No such friend");
}
```

And similarly for `getPersons`, so you would do:

```
printf("\n%s", p.getPerson(0).getFriend(0)->getName().c_str());
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and it would throw an exception instead of dereferencing a garbage pointer.

Comment: Will try to apply the remarks to my program and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, please get into the habit of avoiding passing or returning objects by value, except when you have a known reason for it. If you can't say 'I know I need to take a copy of this object', then pass/return by reference (or pointer if applicable).

Comment: Thank you for the input! Got my problem solved thank to your answer. Will try to apply the other suggestion in my applications from now on.